# Passing a Variable between forms (colour values)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm still new to c# and been playing around a bit, for my project I have these two forms,
on form 1 I have these variables

```
 Color ColCurrentPrimary = Color.FromArgb(35, 39, 42);
 Color ColCurrentSecondary = Color.FromArgb(44, 47, 51);
```

On form 2

I have a window dialog, and this should keep the same theme

e.g:

```
this.BackColor = ColCurrentPrimary;
this.ForeColor = ColCurrentSecondary;
```

However, ColCurrent Primary and secondary don't exist on Form 2, how would I go about passing them? or is there a "Global" that can be accessed from both forms?

any advice would be much appreciated,

thank you for reading,

Samuel

Comment: You need a global static class that you can use in every form of your application. Call it "Config" and create the properties you need to share then initialize it in your main form (via user input or via a config file) and then use in your other forms

Comment: It depends on how you are using these colors.  If you set them on one form (and, say, the user can manipulate them) and you want them to be read on another form, make them a public "get-able" property of the form.  Then, code on Form2 can access the data if it has a reference to Form1

Comment: @Steve initialize a static class? I think what you are trying to describe is a Singleton.

Comment: @SamW I was talking about initializing the properties to some value. Singleton is another way to go, but I think that this is a simple scenario where the difference between the two approaches is not really meaningful in any way.

Comment: @Steve ahh, ok I gotcha. That would probably be a simpler solution. I tend to default to singletons because our work applications use a lot of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that would work very well for you would be a [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). Read through that page - it will tell you everything you need to know about creating one. Once you have it, you can initialize it's properties from either a config file or just set them in code - then the class can be used globally to configure any new forms.

This is what I usually use:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    //add public properties here to use for your config!
    public Color ColCurrentPrimary { get; set; }

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Singleton.Instance.ColCurrentPrimary
```

As Steve has mentioned, you could use a static class also. That may be simpler for your case. Singletons are great for multi threaded applications but may be a little overkill for this. Here is an example of a static class:

```
static class Config
{
    public static Color ColCurrentPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Config.ColCurrentPrimary
```

You just have to make sure that you define the class in a namespace that you will have access to where you need to access it, or add a `using` statement to make it accessible.

Comment: Thanks that's great!